# Are non-pointer instance variables stored on the heap?

Tags: c++, variables, memory

The difference between stack and heap is well documented when in the context of a local function, but I'm curious about instance variables.

Since an instance variable needs to stick around until it is released, is it stored in the same type of memory regardless of whether it is created with `new` or not?

i.e.

```
Class A{
  SomeType s1;
  SomeType * s2;
 }
```

If these were automatic local variables, the difference between these two mechanisms is considerable. But as instance variables, they are more or less in the same place in memory, both on the heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non pointer variables are defined in storage areas depending on ***how*** or ***where*** they are declared.

```
Myclass obj;
```

at function scope will be created on automatic storage while if created at global scope will be created with static storage duration.

In your example, both `A::s1` and `A::s2` will have the same storage area as the object to which they belong. However, since `A::s2` is a pointer it might point to a object which might be placed in different storage area.

For example:

```
void doSomething()
{    
    A obj;
    SomeType obj2;
    obj.s2 = &obj2;
}
```

`A::s2` points to a object whose storage is same as `obj`, while:

```
void doSomething()
{
    A obj;
    SomeType *ptr = new SomeType;
    obj.s2 = ptr;
}
```

`A::s2` points to a object which is dynamically allocated.

<sup>Note: Above code assumes `A::s2` to be `public` for sake of simplicity.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`A::s1` and `A::s2` will be, by definition, stored in whatever way and place that an instance of `A` is created.  As for the location of the storage pointed to by `A::s2`, it could be anywhere.

Comment: @ldgorman §3.7.5 "The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and array elements is that of their complete
object"

Comment: @ldgorman: apart from msam's nice reference to the standard, you can write a test program on your platform of choice to verify it empirically.  For example, declare local variables of type `SomeType` followed by `A` followed by `SomeType` again.  Note that the addresses will be roughly consecutive, as will the address of the members of `A` (but not necessarily the address pointed to by `A::s2`).